# String interpolation for expression in associative array

Tags: php

i have a definition like :

```
define('LIBRARIES_URI', get_template_directory_uri() . '/libraries/');
```

Now, i have an associative array like :

```
array( 'name' => 'superfish-css', 'path' => LIBRARIES_URI .'superfish/css/superfish.css', 'type' => 'style' )
```

However, path is not right, this gives me an error, because there is an expression i guess. I tried various things like double quotes and stuff, but i cannot seem to get it right without an external variable. Is there a way to correctly interpolate that ?

FULL EXAMPLE :

```
define('LIBRARIES_PATH', TEMPLATEPATH . '/libraries/');


class Kosmos
{

  private static $inclusions = array(

    array( 'name' => 'style.css', 'path' => "get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')", 'type' => 'style' ),
    array( 'name' => 'jquery', 'path' => '', 'type' => 'script' ),
    array( 'name' => 'jquery-ui-core', 'path' => '', 'type' => 'script' ),
    array( 'name' => 'jquery-ui-tabs', 'path' => '', 'type' => 'script' ),
    array( 'name' => 'superfish-css', 'path' => LIBRARIES_URI .'superfish/css/superfish.css', 'type' => 'style' ),
    array( 'name' => 'superfish-js', 'path' => "LIBRARIES_URI . 'superfish/js/superfish.js'", 'type' => 'script', 'dep' => array('jquery') ),
    array( 'name' => 'superfish-hover', 'path' => "LIBRARIES_URI . 'superfish/js/hoverIntent.js'", 'type' => 'script', 'dep' => array('jquery') ),
    array( 'name' => 'jquery-color', 'path' => "LIBRARIES_URI . 'horizontalMenu/jquery.color-RGBa-patch.js'", 'type' => 'script' ),

    /* admin */

    array( 'name' => 'admin-css', 'path' => "ADMIN_CSS_URI . 'admin.css'", 'type' => 'admin-style' ),
    array( 'name' => 'tabs-js', 'path' => "LIBRARIES_URI . 'tabs/tabs.js'", 'type' => 'admin-script' )

  );

  private static $admin_inclusions = array();

  public function inclusions() {
    return self::$inclusions;
  }

  public function admin_inclusions() {
    return self::$admin_inclusions;
  }  


}
```

Comment: What's the specific error that you are getting?

Comment: I don't see any error here ...

Comment: Ummm, could you be a little bit more precise in what error you get? This works for me if I add `function get_remplate_directory_uri() {return '/var/www';}` to the top.

Comment: paste `get_template_directory_uri` please...

Comment: Surmising from the question, you are trying to declare a class property with an expression. That's not possible. Assign the attribute in the constructor.

Comment: The error is "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'". Btw, this is actually an array of arrays. Like $array = (array(), array() ...). If i remove this line, the other arrays work fine, so this definitely is the one that causes the error.

Comment: LIBRARIES_URI is definitely correct, it's been used extensively in other places.

Comment: @mario, are you talking about this http://ideone.com/p88V0 ?

Comment: @SpyrosP Can you [upload](http://codepad.org) an example that demonstrates the problem? Come on, with 6k rep, you should now better than "it doesn't work" ;)

Comment: @SpyrosP, paste entire code, you probably have syntax error somewhere... should work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Workaround for basic syntax not being parsed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671928/workaround-for-basic-syntax-not-being-parsed)

Comment: Status: Closed Reason: could not reproduce :)

Comment: @webarto: that's really really weird. The error i get seems to be about the '.', as i said before : PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Class attribute declarations may **not** contain expressions, only literal/constant values.
>
> Move your assignment into the constructor.

Comment: ah, interesting, so this why this is happening, i suppose i would have to use another variable then. Let me try it, i guess it's the only way. I probably will not avoid it.

Comment: yeap, i ended up doing it in the constructor. Interesting differentiation. It works fine now.