# Array class property

Tags: php

This code gives the error "unexpected '.', expecting ')'".  Why is this invalid?  I'd thought that as both parts are constant, I could concatenate them.  New to PHP.  Thanks.

```
class c {
  const HELLO = 'hello';
  public $arr = array(
    'hw' => self::HELLO . 'world'
  );
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Workaround for basic syntax not being parsed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671928/workaround-for-basic-syntax-not-being-parsed)

Comment: you should accept the answer below to reward the person who helped you. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class properties must have constant initial values.  The concatenation of those two strings is NOT a constant value.

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.properties.php):

> [Property] declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization **must be a constant value** -- that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

You could put the property initialisation in your constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->arr = array(
    'hw' => self::HELLO . 'world'
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had thought it would be constant.  Though I do now see the point that the operator makes it an expression.