# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

This thing is bugging me a lot. I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' at this line

```
public static $user_table = TABLE_PREFIX . 'users';
```

TABLE_PREFIX is a constant created by define function

Comment: echo the constant and see if its getting the value...

Comment: Probably the problem is in your constant so you might put that definition up for us to see as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attribute declarations in a class definition can only be constant values, not expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671928/workaround-for-basic-syntax-not-being-parsed)

Comment: @sree If I echo TABLE_PREFIX and users separately, it works. But cannot concatenate both of them

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313051/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-or-in)

Comment: Definitely shouldn't be closed as too localised - helped me, and I'm in *the future!!!* dealing with an ancient PHP version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Static class properties are initialized at compile time.  You cannot use a constant `TABLE_PREFIX` to concatenate with a string literal when initializing a static class property, since the constant's value is not known until runtime.  Instead, initialize it in the constructor:

```
public static $user_table;

// Initialize it in the constructor 
public function __construct() {
  self::$user_table = TABLE_PREFIX . 'users';
}

// If you only plan to use it in static context rather than instance context 
// (won't call a constructor) initialize it in a static function instead 
public static function init() {
  self::$user_table = TABLE_PREFIX . 'users';
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.

#### Update for PHP >= 5.6

PHP 5.6 brought limited support for expressions:

> In PHP 5.6 and later, the same rules apply as const expressions: some limited expressions are possible, provided they can be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 8):

The dot is a string concatenation operator. It's a runtime function, so it can't be used to declare a static (parsetime) value.