# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am recieveing the following parse error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in
>   H:\Programs\USBWebserver
>   v8.5\8.5\root\oopforum\func\register.class.php on line 7

which relates to the following line of code in my class:

```
private $random_name = rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999);
```

I can not see why this line of code would cause a parse error?

Here is some surrounding code:

```
class register{
    public $post_data = array();
        private $dbh;
        private $allowed_type = array('image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif');
        private $random_name = rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999);
        private $path = 'img/thumb_/'.$random_name. $_FILES['file']['name'];
        private $max_width = 4040;
        private $max_height = 4040;
        private $max_size = 5242880;
        private $temp_dir = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        private $image_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        private $image_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        private $image_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        private $image_dimensions = getimagesize($temp_dir);
        private $image_width = $image_dimensions[0]; // Image width
        private $image_height = $image_dimensions[1]; // Image height
        private $error = array();

        public function __construct($post_data, PDO $dbh){
        $this->post_data = array_map('trim', $post_data);
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
        }
}
```

What is causing the parse error?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't initialize member variables to anything that is not static, and you're trying to call a function.

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

The workaround is to set your variable in the constructor:

```
private $random_name;
public function __construct() { 
    $this->random_name = rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999);
}
```

Comment: Thanks..I removed everything else except the line to set the $random_name variable and placed that inside the __construct() and it gives me this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRIVATE in H:\Programs\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\oopforum\func\register.class.php on line 14`

Comment: You'll have to update your question with the full class to determine that error, as it's likely unrelated to your previous one.

Comment: @crm - You need to put `private $random_name;` outside of the constructor, then copy the line inside the constructor exactly as it is in my post. I've updated my answer to show how it is done.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this:

```
private $image_dimensions = getimagesize($temp_dir);
```

Functions, variables, and anything else not static can't be called to set class variables.