# Why I can't use get_cfg_var() to assign a custom setting value to an instance variable

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313051/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-or-in)

I am doing the following:

```
<?php
class JConfig {
    public $var = get_cfg_var('mySetting');
}
?>
```

If I do that I received a compile error that says:

> syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'

If I do `echo get_cfg_var('mySetting')` outside the class it works just fine.
If I assign `get_cfg_var('mySetting')` to a local variable it works just fine.

Anyone has any idea why I can't assign it to a instance variable?

Comment: this is not a duplicate questions, the Parse error stated above is an error that can be thrown for many reasons.

Comment: Click the link. The problem and the answer are identical, therefore, it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> [Property] declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization **must be a constant value**--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

You will need to initialize that value from the class constructor or from somewhere else in your code.