# PHP string not concatonating

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘(’, expecting ‘,’ or ‘;’ in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313051/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-or-in)

I'm getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in xxx
>   on line 19

On this line:

```
public $metad_name = "lol" . "lol";
```

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes. It's a dupe almost for sure, but not a bad question per-se.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is saying that an expression can't be used in class properties:

### Works

```
class Foo {

    public $metad_name = '';

    function __construct() {
        $this->metad_name = 'lol' . 'lol';
    }

}
```

### Parse error

```
class Bar {

    public $metad_name = 'lol' . 'lol';

}
```

If your code isn't a class property - just delete the `public`