# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting '(' in

Tags: php, syntax-error, php-parse-error

I've been trying to do a ranking system for a friend.
Everything's ready, but an error gets in the way.
The error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting '(' in /blablabla/sn_rank.php on line 8
```

Here's my code:

```
<?
function lul($pts, $low, $high) {
if($pts <= $low) return false;
if($pts >= $high) return false;
return true;
}
function get_rank($pts){
if lul($pts, "0", "75"){
return "Newcomer";
}
if lul($pts, "75", "175"){
return "Junior";
}
if lul($pts, "175", "325"){
return "Senior";
}
if lul($pts,"325", "525"){
return "Advanced";
}
if lul($pts, "525", "775"){
return "Veteran";
}
}
echo get_rank($_GET['pts']);
?>
```

Please don't downnote, I'm new here.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to wrap your if statements inside brackets - `if (lul($pts, "0", "75")){`

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that :P

Comment: I would also recommend getting an IDE like Netbeans so errors like these are picked up "automatically".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313051/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-or-in)

Comment: @ColeJohnson No it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for if is, according to http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#284:

```
if (expr)
```

So use every time:

```
if (lul(...)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
if(lul($pts, "0", "75")){
  return "Newcomer";
}
```

Notice how it is wrapped in brackets?