# Syntax error when trying to put together constant and string

Tags: php, syntax

Normally i wouldn't post syntax errors here, but this case is a bit suspicious to me. I was trying to put together a constant with a string. I works fine on localhost, but when i push my project on my web server, it tells me:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in xxx on line xxx
```

Code:

```
define("ROOT", str_replace("index.php", "", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]));
```

and

```
$somePath = ROOT . "some/path"; //Synax error in this line
```

Has this something to do with different PHP versions? (5.5 on webserver, 7.0 localhost)

**Update**

Some updates in the code:

```
class SomeClass {

    private $somePath = ROOT . "some/path"; //Synax error in this line

    ...
}
```

Comment: did you include the page?

Comment: I'm using exact the same code as on localhost

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Please make sure you show us the full, real and relevant code here. Also read and provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: This might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969342/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-or

Comment: Updated problem

Comment: You can't have an expression in an instance property definition iirc. (At least in your PHP version). Put it in the constructor.

Comment: Does it work with PHP 7?

Comment: Does appear to work without error on 5.6+

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `str_replace()` nor any function when defining a contant. Try:

```
define("ROOT", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
$somePath = str_replace("index.php", "", ROOT) . "some/path";
```

Please refer to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php):

> In PHP 5, value must be a scalar value (integer, float, string, boolean, or NULL). In PHP 7, array values are also accepted.