# Bing Ads API V12- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, bing-ads-api

I am using **Bing Ads API V12** for php to do some Ads service related operations. The script I am using to get bing ads cost on daily basis with scheduler. Everything works fine when I try it with php **v7.0** but If I try it with php **v5.6.30** it is causing parse error on line 53 of AuthHelper.php

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' on line 53
```

The main library block on line 53 AuthHelper.php  is like this on the **final** class with other **const**

```
const CampaignTypes = 
    CampaignType::Audience . ' ' . 
    CampaignType::Search . ' ' . 
    CampaignType::Shopping . ' ' . 
    CampaignType::DynamicSearchAds;
```

**Full ref. of AuthHelper class**

https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-PHP-SDK/blob/master/samples/V12/AuthHelper.php

**Possible duplicate:**
[Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969342/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-or)

So my question is how could I fix it now? 
Should I wrap it with constructor ? Or anything else quick fix?

Comment: If you insist on the outdated PHP version, then yes, you'll have to use the constructor. Constant scalar expressions are not supported with PHP5.

Comment: On PHP 5.6+ you wouldn't have this issue, The lib requires >=5.6: https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-PHP-SDK/blob/master/composer.json#L9

Comment: But I am having this issue on php v5.6.30 !!!!!! Works perfectly on v7.0

Comment: @mario Support for constant scalar expressions was [added in 5.6.0](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php).

Comment: Check your version, v5.6.30 should be fine.. https://3v4l.org/COpVo

Comment: @Lawrence Yes you're ri8, I've found why I'm having  that error. Actually one of my fellow developer installed the 5.6 without removing/disabling the older php v5.5, so when I try with php -v it shows me the cli version(also I didn't notice somehow :( ),  but web version is still running on php v5.5 when I saw the phpinfo(). It should work and it is working, thnx for the demo link