# Why can't I declare a "date" in a class?

Tags: php, oop

I don't really know what to google, as I have kind of picked up PHP and OOP without knowing the jargon.

Why doesn't this work in PHP?

```
class Calendar{
    public $derp="lala";
    public $todaysDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2013-04-11'));
}
```

But this does?

```
class Calendar{
    public $derp="lala";
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->todaysDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2013-04-11'));
    }
}
```

You can't declare a date at the beginning of a class? Why?

Comment: * [Attribute declarations in a class definition can only be constant values, not expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671928/workaround-for-basic-syntax-not-being-parsed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

TL;DR You cannot initialize properties with non constant values. Functions are not constant values.

> Properties
>
> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them referred to using other terms such 
>   as "attributes" or "fields", but for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are 
>   defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable
>   declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant 
>   value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time 
>   information in order to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

`date` is a function. Functions are called from methods. Plus giving your `$todaysDate` variable a value is more appropriate in the constructor.