# Syntax error when trying to create array of anonymous functions

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I am trying to realize my own MVC framework and invented a very nice way to provide definitions of virtual fields and additional relations.

According to some other high-voted post on stackoverflow, this should actually work:

```
class User extends Model {

  public $hasOne = array('UserSetting');

  public $validate = array();

  public $virtualFields = array(
      'fullname' => function () {
          return $this->fname . ($this->mname ? ' ' . $this->mname : '') . ' ' . $this->lname;
      },
      'official_fullname' => function () {

      }
  );
}
```

But it doesn't work. It says: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION**. What am I doing wrong?

PS. talking about this one [Can you store a function in a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499862/can-you-store-a-function-in-a-php-array)

Comment: no, I've checked it. It is 5.3.8.

Comment: Attribute declarations in a class definition can only be [constant values, not expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671928/workaround-for-basic-syntax-not-being-parsed). And anonymous functions simply aren't primitive types or structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define the methods in the constructor, or some other method, not directly in the class member declaration.

```
class User extends Model {

  public $hasOne = array('UserSetting');

  public $validate = array();

  public $virtualFields = array();

  public function __construct() {
     $this->virtualFields = array(
        'fullname' => function () {
            return $this->fname . ($this->mname ? ' ' . $this->mname : '') . ' ' . $this->lname;
        },
        'official_fullname' => function () {

        }
    );
  }
}
```

While that works, PHP's magic method `__get()` is better suited to this task:

```
class User extends Model {

  public $hasOne = array('UserSetting');

  public $validate = array();

  public function __get($key) {
     switch ($key) {
       case 'fullname':
           return $this->fname . ($this->mname ? ' ' . $this->mname : '') . ' ' . $this->lname;
       break;

       case 'official_fullname':
         return '';
       break;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. It's a little pity, however, because it isn't that clear and elegant as my idea originally was. Also because my constructor is a little bit more complicated and can accept some more arguments, which have to be passed through parent::__construct. But well, it is still pretty cool. Thanks again. I +1-ed it.

Comment: @BarthZalewski you may consider looking into PHP's magic methods, `__get()`, `__call()` and `__callStatic()`. Those methods are better suited to this sort of thing and will keep your constructor clean. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php